# How can I achieve full minification with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have some trouble obtaining a truly minified bundle using `webpack` and `uglify-loader`.

Here is the setup

**Content of `app.js` :**

```
var React = require('react');
module.exports = 'just a string';
```

**Content of `webpack.config.js`**

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'uglify',
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**The problem**

By looking at `bundle.js`, we can see that only partial minification has occured. The file is 1055 lines long, and is filled with a bunch of `/******/`.

How can I achieve true minification with webpack ? Using the `uglify-loader` is not mandatory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the UglifyJsPlugin from webpack; you specify it in the plugins section of your webpack configuration file:

```
  var webpack = require('webpack');
     plugins: [
         new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
             compress: {
                 screw_ie8: true,
                 warnings: false
             }
         })
     ]
```

For more informations about UglifyJsPlugin which minimize all JavaScript output of chunks. 
https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks ! I appreciate the `screw_ie8` option :D